# Не могу пушить на GitHub - "Password authentication is temporarily disabled"

Tags: git, github

Не получается пушить. Ввожу `git push` и получаю ошибку:

```
remote: Password authentication is temporarily disabled as part of a brownout. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-07-30-token-authentication-requirements-for-api-and-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/example/example.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

После этого создал токен, но как связать с `git`...

Comment: чем только люди не страдают, лишь бы не пользоваться протоколом ssh в качестве транспорта…

Comment: В списке гитхаба написано как связать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно просто токен ввести как пароль.

Если он не запрашивает его каждый раз у тебя, значит его нужно поменять где-то в конфиге: если ты на линуксе, то пароль хранится в `~/.git-credentials`, там я думаю разберёшься где он. Если на винде, то не уверен как там это работает. Посмотри как изменить пароль в гите и просто вместо пароля используй токен